# Android - Change FAB icon when an element into ListView is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I have a `ListView` inside a `Fragment` that contains some songs. When I click on a song, I want to change the icon inside the FAB (that is placed in `Activity`) but I don't know how can I do it. I've tried with this code:

FRAGMENT:

```
mainActivity = new MainActivity();  //THIS IS INSIDE onCreate METHOD

mListViewSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mainActivity.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_pause);
         }
    }
```

I declared my FAB as public inside my Activity, but I still get NullPointerException, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your fab is inside your activity, you need a way to communicate between your fragment and you activity. I recommend following this guide [this guide](http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activities/).

Essentially, you want to define an interface `ActivityController` that contains any functions you want to run inside the activity. Here is a mockup example:

`ActivityController.java` - A new interface you will create

```
public interface ActivityController {
    void setFabImageResource(int resourceId);
}
```

`MainActivity.java` - Modifiy your activity as necessary.

```
public class MainActivity implements ActivityController {
    //The rest of your code

    public void setFabImageResource(int resourceId) {
        fab.setImageResource(resourceId);
    }
}
```

`YourFragment.java` - Just modifiy your fragment like so:

```
mListViewSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((ActivityController)getActivity()).setFabImageResource(R.drawable.vector_pause);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
mainActivity.fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_pause);
```

by

```
fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector_pause);
```

I am assuming that `fab` is declared as

```
FloatingActionButton fab;
```

and that you are assigning it like

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.your_fab_id_from_xml);
```

after calling `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`.

Remember that you should never create activity instances yourself. This is a role of the framework, not yours.

Comment: You might want to add that you assume the fab is inside the fragment.

Comment: It's not. It's said it's in the Activity. I will update my answer.

Comment: Whoops yea I meant activity. Either way it is important to denote which one you are talking about